# Expresion regular estructura de un string

Tags: regex

Dada esta estructura `xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx`  donde las `x` pueden ser cualquier número entre el 0-9, ¿Cuál seria su expresión regular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería esta expresión:

```
\d{9}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{9}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es: `\d` reconoce un dígito, seguido por `{n}` que hace que el digito anterior se repita **n** veces. Los guiones los interpreta tal cual.

Puedes probar aquí:

https://regex101.com/r/AWeKAR/1

Comment: Podrias explicar tu expresión regular?

Comment: @Chistian Editada la respuesta

Comment: Muy bien!!, asi mas gente podra entenderla, sin tener un conocimiento previo